# How to pass form fields from one page to another page in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

**Checkout.js**

> This is the checkout.js file. In this file, I returned the Checkout Form, and Now I want to use the form fields of the checkout form page.
>
> The question is how will I get the form fields of the CheckoutForm page and use them on this page which is checkout.js. Because I want to submit the form data in the database. But the form is on another page and the submit button is on another page e.g. (checkout.js page)

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Stepper from '@material-ui/core/Stepper';
import Step from '@material-ui/core/Step';
import StepLabel from '@material-ui/core/StepLabel';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import AddressForm from './CheckoutForm';
import PaymentForm from './PaymentForm';
import Review from './Review';



function Copyright() {
    return (
        <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" align="center">
            {'Copyright © '}
            <Link color="inherit" href="https://material-ui.com/">
                Your Website
      </Link>{' '}
            {new Date().getFullYear()}
            {'.'}
        </Typography>
    );
}
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    appBar: {
        position: 'relative',
    },

    layout: {
        width: 'auto',
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(2),
        marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
        [theme.breakpoints.up(1000 + theme.spacing(2) * 2)]: {
            width: 1100,
            marginLeft: 'auto',
            marginRight: 'auto',

        },

    },
    paper: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
        marginBottom: theme.spacing(3),
        padding: theme.spacing(2),
        [theme.breakpoints.up(700 + theme.spacing(3) * 2)]: {
            marginTop: theme.spacing(6),
            marginBottom: theme.spacing(6),
            padding: theme.spacing(3),
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(248, 246, 244)',

        },

    },
    stepper: {
        padding: theme.spacing(5, 0, 5),
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(248, 246, 244)',


    },
    buttons: {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',

    },
    button: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
        border: "none"    
    },
}));

const steps = ['Shipping address', 'Payment details', 'Review your order'];

function getStepContent(step) {
    switch (step) {
        case 0:
            return <AddressForm/>;
        case 1:
            return <PaymentForm />;
        case 2:
            return <Review />;
        default:
            throw new Error('Unknown step');
    }
}

export default function Checkout(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);

    const handleNext = () => {
        setActiveStep(activeStep + 1);
    

    };

    const handleBack = () => {
        setActiveStep(activeStep - 1);
    };

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <CssBaseline />
            <AppBar position="absolute" color="default" className={classes.appBar}></AppBar>
            <main className={classes.layout}>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                    <Typography component="h1" variant="h3" align="center">
                        Checkout
          </Typography>
                    <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} className={classes.stepper}>
                        {steps.map((label) => (
                            <Step key={label}>
                                <StepLabel><Typography component="h1" variant="h5" align="center">
                                    {label} </Typography></StepLabel>
                            </Step>
                        ))}
                    </Stepper>

                    <React.Fragment>
                        {activeStep === steps.length ? (
                            <React.Fragment>
                                <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
                                    Thank you for your order.
                </Typography>
                                <Typography variant="subtitle1">
                                    Your order number is #2001539. We have emailed your order 
                                     confirmation, and will
                                     send you an update when your order has shipped.
                </Typography>
                            </React.Fragment>
                        ) : (
                                <React.Fragment>
                                    {getStepContent(activeStep)}
                              {    <div className={classes.buttons}>
                                        {activeStep !== 0 && (
                                            <Button variant="contained" style={{outline: 'none'}} 
                                        onClick={handleBack} className={classes.button}>
                                                Back
                                            </Button>
                                        )}
                                        <Button style={{outline: 'none'}}
                                            variant="contained"
                                            color="secondary"
                                            onClick={handleNext}
                                            className={classes.button}
                                        >
                                            {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'Place order' : 'Next'}
                                        </Button>
                                    </div> }
                                </React.Fragment>
                            )}
                    </React.Fragment>
                </Paper>
                <Copyright />
            </main>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

**CheckoutForm.js**

> In this file I used the Form I want to access this form fields ( for example first name, last name, and other fields ) in the checkout.js file. How can I do that? Any suggestions?

```
import React from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import './CheckoutForm.scss'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';


export default function AddressForm() {
  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  buttons: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',

},
button: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    border: "none"    
},
}));

const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>
        Customer Information
      </Typography><br /><br />

      <Grid container fluid spacing={3} >
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} >
          <label for="Firstname">Firstname</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="Firstname" />

        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <label for="Lastname">Lastname</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" placeholder="Lastname" />

        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <label for="Address">Address</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Address" />

        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <label for="City">City</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity" placeholder="City" />

        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <label for="State">State</label>

          <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
            <option>Pakistan</option>
          </select>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion, you pass `addressValues` object and `changeAddressValue` function to `CheckoutForm.js` from `checkout.js`, addressValues is an object that has all values that user fills in the AddressForm i.e firstname, lastname, address etc, this object is controlled by a state in `checkout.js`, whenever user changes a value in the `AddressForm/CheckoutForm`, `changeAddressValue` function updates a values - addressFormValues in the `checkout.js`, this will make it easy when you submit the form on `checkout.js` because all the values will have already been populated on the `addressFormValues` state i.e `const [addressFormValues, setAddressFormValues] = React.useState({});`

### Here is my solution:

#### CheckoutForm.js

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types */
import React from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import './CheckoutForm.scss';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  buttons: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',

  },
  button: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    border: "none"    
  },
}));

const AddressForm = ({ addressValues, changeAddressValue }) => {

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>
        Customer Information
      </Typography><br /><br />

      <Grid container fluid spacing={3} >
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} >
          <label for="Firstname">Firstname</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="Firstname"  value={addressValues.firstname} onChange={(e) => changeAddressValue('firstname', e.target.value)} />

        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <label for="Lastname">Lastname</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" placeholder="Lastname" value={addressValues.lastname} onChange={(e) => changeAddressValue('lastname', e.target.value)} />

        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <label for="Address">Address</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Address" value={addressValues.address} onChange={(e) => changeAddressValue('address', e.target.value)} />

        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <label for="City">City</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity" placeholder="City" value={addressValues.city} onChange={(e) => changeAddressValue('city', e.target.value)} />

        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <label for="State">State</label>

          <select id="inputState" class="form-control" >
            <option>Pakistan</option>
          </select>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default AddressForm;
```

#### PaymentForm.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import { createStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import StripeCheckout from 'react-stripe-checkout';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';


const styles = createStyles({
  formControlLabel: {
    fontSize: '1.5rem',
    '& label': { fontSize: '5rem' }
  }
});

const handleToken = (token) => {

  console.log(token);
};

const PaymentForm = ({ paymentFormValues, changePaymentFormValue }) => {

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom>
                Payment method
      </Typography><br />
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox checked={paymentFormValues['checkedA']} onChange={(e) => changePaymentFormValue('checkedA', e.target.checked)} />}
            label={<Typography style={styles.formControlLabel}>Cash on 
                 delivery</Typography>}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <StripeCheckout
            stripeKey="pk_test_51I9XPQAesAg2GfzQyVB7VgP0IbmWwgcfeFJSuCpB2kbNu60AFTbFhC7dxwje8YF4w2ILMJ6o2InB9ENczpd4dCSa00e09XoDbw"
            token={handleToken}
            amount={2 * 100}
            name="All Products"

          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default PaymentForm;
```

#### Checkout.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Stepper from '@material-ui/core/Stepper';
import Step from '@material-ui/core/Step';
import StepLabel from '@material-ui/core/StepLabel';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import AddressForm from './CheckoutForm';
import PaymentForm from './PaymentForm';
import Review from './Review';


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  appBar: {
    position: 'relative',
  },

  layout: {
    width: 'auto',
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(2),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    [theme.breakpoints.up(1000 + theme.spacing(2) * 2)]: {
      width: 1100,
      marginLeft: 'auto',
      marginRight: 'auto',

    },

  },
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(3),
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    [theme.breakpoints.up(700 + theme.spacing(3) * 2)]: {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(6),
      marginBottom: theme.spacing(6),
      padding: theme.spacing(3),
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(248, 246, 244)',

    },

  },
  stepper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(5, 0, 5),
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(248, 246, 244)',


  },
  buttons: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',

  },
  button: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    border: "none"    
  },
}));

const steps = ['Shipping address', 'Payment details', 'Review your order'];

function Copyright() {
  return (
    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" align="center">
      {'Copyright © '}
      <Link color="inherit" href="https://material-ui.com/">
                  Your Website
      </Link>{' '}
      {new Date().getFullYear()}
      {'.'}
    </Typography>
  );
}

function getStepContent(step, formValues = null, changeFormValue = null) {
  switch (step) {
  case 0:
    return <AddressForm addressValues={formValues} changeAddressValue={changeFormValue} />;
  case 1:
    return <PaymentForm paymentFormValues={formValues} changePaymentFormValue={changeFormValue}  />;
  case 2:
    return <Review />;
  default:
    throw new Error('Unknown step');
  }
}

export default function Checkout(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [paymentFormValues, setPaymentFormValues] = React.useState({});
  const [addressFormValues, setAddressFormValues] = React.useState({});
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);

  const handleNext = () => {
    setActiveStep(activeStep + 1);
  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep(activeStep - 1);
  };

  const changeAddressFormValue = (key, value) => {
    let values = { ...addressFormValues };
    values[key] = value;
    setAddressFormValues(values);
  };

  const changePaymentFormValue = (key, value) => {
    let values = { ...paymentFormValues };
    values[key] = value;
    setPaymentFormValues(values);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar position="absolute" color="default" className={classes.appBar}></AppBar>
      <main className={classes.layout}>
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>
          <Typography component="h1" variant="h3" align="center">
                        Checkout
          </Typography>
          <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} className={classes.stepper}>
            {steps.map((label) => (
              <Step key={label}>
                <StepLabel><Typography component="h1" variant="h5" align="center">
                  {label} </Typography></StepLabel>
              </Step>
            ))}
          </Stepper>

          <React.Fragment>
            {activeStep === steps.length ? (
              <React.Fragment>
                <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
                                    Thank you for your order.
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="subtitle1">
                                    Your order number is #2001539. We have emailed your order 
                                     confirmation, and will
                                     send you an update when your order has shipped.
                </Typography>
              </React.Fragment>
            ) : (
              <React.Fragment>
                {
                  activeStep === 0 ? 
                    getStepContent(activeStep, addressFormValues, changeAddressFormValue)
                    : activeStep === 1 ?  getStepContent(activeStep, paymentFormValues, changePaymentFormValue)
                      : getStepContent(activeStep)
                }
                {activeStep === 0 ? <Button onClick={() => {
                  // All the address values will be availabe in addressFormValues object for further processes
                  console.log(addressFormValues);
                }} >Submit Address</Button> : null}
                {    <div className={classes.buttons}>
                  {activeStep !== 0 && (
                    <Button variant="contained" style={{outline: 'none'}} 
                      className={classes.button}
                      onClick={handleBack}
                    >
                        Back
                    </Button>
                  )}
                  <Button style={{outline: 'none'}}
                    variant="contained"
                    color="secondary"
                    onClick={handleNext}
                    className={classes.button}
                  >
                    {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'Place order' : 'Next'}
                  </Button>
                </div> }
              </React.Fragment>
            )}
          </React.Fragment>
        </Paper>
        <Copyright />
      </main>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```